# How to hide google adsence advert in a page for certain countries?

Tags: adsense

I am a blogger and place google ads in my blog. I do not want to these ads to show up in certain countries is there any additional code I can use in my page that can help me achieve this.

For an example i do not want advert to show in Germany. Any Advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use API from http://www.geoplugin.net/

Eg. in PHP

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=".getRealIpAddr());
    $country = $xml->geoplugin_countryName ;
    if($country != "Germany")
    {?>
       <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- Horizontal Big Banner -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:inline-block;width:970px;height:250px"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX"
             data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXX"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>

    <?php
     }



//For getting IP Address

    function getRealIpAddr()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jenson, Yes my site is a PHP site but can you tell me how to integrate it in the page. for an example if my adsence code is <script> adsence code </scritp> then where should i put this code?/

Comment: @creativated_dev I've updated the answer. You can put this condition where your page actually show ads.

Comment: thanks I will give it a try and will let you know if I get any difficulty. Thank again.

Comment: @creativated_dev Alright. If this would help resolving your issue, You can upvote & accept the answer later.

Comment: That did not work. Is there any code i can put in the header.php in literal tag? FYI my site is based on prestashop.

Comment: @creativated_dev Are you using CMS like Wordpress or Core PHP??

Comment: Yes,I am using prestashop

Comment: @creativated_dev You need to follow their file/folder structure to customize the same.

Comment: Lets say I have to do it in HTML page then what would be your advise?

Comment: @creativated_dev First, You need to have control of the page displaying ad. You can do with PHP or JavaScript like I said before **if** you know the correct page.

Comment: I know the page in which I have placed the Adsence code. I am pasting the additional code in the same location.

Comment: Can I've look on that particular page?? Share jenson555[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: sent you an email.